# Add 'Detail Page Button' to Contact Layout using the MetaData API

Tags: apex, metadata-api

In my package I created a Detail Page Button that executes some Javascript. The intention is be able to add this to the Contact layout using the Metadata API.

I looked in eclipse and this is the metadata generated for my button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <webLinks>
        <fullName>myCustomContactButton</fullName>
        <availability>online</availability>
        <displayType>button</displayType>
        <linkType>javascript</linkType>
        <masterLabel>Use My Button</masterLabel>
        <openType>onClickJavaScript</openType>
        <protected>false</protected>
        <url>var url = &apos;/apex/CustomVfAction?Id={!Contact.Id}&apos;; //string for the URL of the 
parent.location.href = url; //refresh the page</url>
    </webLinks>
</CustomObject>
```

And here is how I am attempting to add to the layout (following the instructions from https://andyinthecloud.com/2014/04/24/apex-metadata-api-and-spring14-keys-to-the-kingdom/)

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

// Read the Layout
            MetadataService.Layout layout =
                (MetadataService.Layout) service.readMetadata('Layout',
                    new String[] { 'Contact Layout' }).getRecords()[0];

            // Add the Custom Button to the Layout
            if(layout.customButtons==null)
                layout.customButtons = new List<String>();

            layout.customButtons.add('myCustomContactButton');
```

However this is throwing an exception in Apex - it's not very helpful though. It simply says "Webservice returned a SOAP fault: UNKNOWN EXCEPTION".

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or how to troubleshoot this? I'm not very familiar with the MetaData API.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, I think you are mentioning the Layout name in a wrong way, it will be '**Contact-Contact Layout**'.

Here is the working code to create button and adding it to layout-

```
MetadataService.WebLink webLink = new MetadataService.WebLink();
webLink.fullName = 'Contact.googleButton';
webLink.availability = 'online';
webLink.displayType = 'button';
webLink.encodingKey = 'UTF-8';
webLink.hasMenubar = false;
webLink.hasScrollbars = true;
webLink.hasToolbar = false;
webLink.height = 600;
webLink.isResizable = true;
webLink.linkType = 'url';
webLink.masterLabel = 'google test meta';
webLink.openType = 'newWindow';
webLink.position = 'none';
webLink.protected_x = false;
webLink.showsLocation = false;
webLink.showsStatus = false;
webLink.url = 'http://www.google.com';
webLink.width = 600;
service.createMetadata(new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { webLink })[0];

// Add the Custom Button to the Layout
MetadataService.Layout layout1 = (MetadataService.Layout) service.readMetadata('Layout', new String[] { 'Contact-Contact Layout' }).getRecords()[0];
if(layout1.customButtons==null)
    layout1.customButtons = new List<String>();
layout1.customButtons.add('googleButton');

// Update the Layout
service.updateMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] { layout1 })[0];
```

Comment: In my case then, would the button be called "Contact. myCustomContactButton?" since I already have it created in the package?

Comment: @user1813867 You won't need the button code and need to write layout1.customButtons.add('myCustomContactButton');
I checked it by creating an action button from salesforce admin and added on layout page by running the code like I have just suggested.